# Subquery in Mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm trying to count users signin in DB, the problem is to count uniq signin by date. The problem, user can have a multiple signin a day.

For example table Student
StudentID

Hour
TypeID = StudentID, Date, Time
123, 2014-11-11, 00:11:00
123, 2014-11-11, 00:15:00
123, 2014-11-11, 00:16:00
etc.

I'm trying to use this query...

```
    select count(*) from (
select '1' from Students s LEFT JOIN Hours h on s.StudentID = h.TypeID
where s.StudentID = stud.StudentID
group by h.Date) tmp, Student stud
where s.LastName = 'TestUser'
```

But subquery shows an error: Unknown column stud.StudentID

Comment: Could you make a SQL fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Error is very clear, column StudentID doesn't exists in "stud" alias. You define the alias as "s".
Maybe something like this:

```
select count(*) from (
    select '1' from Students s 
    LEFT JOIN Hours h on s.StudentID = h.TypeID
    where s.StudentID = h.StudentID
    group by h.Date
) tmp
```

But this won't take effect since you have not selected anything.

```
, Student s
where s.LastName = 'TestUser'
```

But I think is still not functionally. What are you trying to do?

Comment: The column is exists in an alias stud
I'm trying to count uniq user visits inside big query.

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
Select h.Date, Count(Distinct TypeID) as tot
From [Hours] as h
Left Join Students s
    On s.StudentID = h.TypeID
where s.LastName = 'TestUser'
Group By h.Date
```